# Is the overlapping of a primary key with a foreign key a bad idea?

Tags: database, foreign-keys, primary-key

What is the best choice?
Split the primary key with the foreign key, so we have 2 fields, or overlap where is possible primary and foreign key?
From a design point of view, is the split the best choice?

Example:

User(pk_id, username, password)

Score(pk_id, fk_user, score)

or

User(pk_id, username, password)

Score(pk_fk_id, score)

Each user can have max 1 row in the table Score.

Comment: ??? what do you mean ?

Comment: I've edited the question for a better explanation.

Comment: If each user can only have one score, it should be a column in user...

Comment: Tony Hopkinson says it all... no need for an extra table. If you really wish to do it with a second table, then you don't need an extra field as PK in this second table, as the user id will also be unique and could be used as PK.

Comment: I have semplified te problem. The score table can be very big and logically separated from the other one. So, in the entire db User table must be with those 3 fields.

Comment: Then the key in 'score' should be userId, Your two choices allow 1 to many, and you've said 1 - 1